# Make $id in foreach loop unique

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, foreach

I am trying to develop a simple comment system.

For every new post, a new list item gets created.

The id of the listitem is AUTO_INCREMENT. The popup should insert the values: id of the post $id, the author of the post $autor and the author of the comment username

Now the problem is that if I set the id of the element listone to the id of the row $row['id'] the id is right. But when I set the id of a listitem to the value of the input element id, the id or something else that I add there have always the same id or time like the last added post/list item.

The second input element which should insert the autor of the post works fine.
How can I make the ID unique?

```
    <div data-role="content">                
        <?php
        include("list.php");
        ?>
            <div data-demo-html="true">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">

                        <?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>

                            <li id ="listone" name="listone"  data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b ui-li-has-count ui-first-child"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></li>
                            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" >
                            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a class="ui-link-inherit"></a><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong></strong><?php echo $row['time']; ?></p>
                                <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['title']; ?></strong></p>
                                <p class="ui-li-desc"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>

                                <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $row['town']; ?></strong></p> 
                     <a href="#popupcomment" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">comment</a>   
                    <button class="commentbtn" data-rel="button" >comment</button>   
            <div id="createcomment" class="comment" data-theme="a" >
    <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
        <div class="content">
        <div id="showcomments" data-theme="a" >
    <?php
include("showcomments.php");
?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $keyComment => $rowComment): ?>
    <div>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><?php echo $rowComment['username']; ?></strong></p>
                        <p class="ui-li-desc"><?php echo $rowComment['comment']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="text" />
         <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>" type="text" />
       <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a"/>          
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>

                            </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
                    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

comments.php :

```
    $hostname='localhost';
        $user='root';
        $password='';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){                    
                try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=searchfood", $user, $password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        // prepare your query
        $query = 'INSERT INTO comments (username, autorpost, comment, id_post, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now())';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        // bind variables
        $stmt->execute(array($_COOKIE['username'], $_POST['autorpost'], $_POST['text'], $_POST['id']));
        // pull last insert id
        $new = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 

        // show success message or redirect, whatever you want
        echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
        $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lendsth/main.php", true, 302);

    }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }

    }
```

Comment: what is *input element id* ?

Comment: This hidden input element and the other hidden element autor should give the required values to comments.php. :)

Comment: How about using an md5 of microtime to create an unique ID (i.e. `md5(microtime(true));`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are naming every input the same. `name="id"` therefor its logic that you will get the last element no matter what form did you submit.

You should give the name attribute some context (since the value of name attr is the one that gets submitted as the form input)

```
<?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>
<form action="./comments.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="authorForm[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>][id]" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> </input>  
   <input type="hidden" name="authorForm[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>][autorpost]" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor']; ?>"></input>
   <textarea rows="1" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a"/>          

</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edited to follow the 1st comment info:

Following is a scirpt that renders a sequence of 2 forms:

```
<?php
$result = array(
    array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => "title_1",
    'text' => "text_1",
    'town' => "town_1",
    'autor' => "autor_1",
    'time' => "time_1"
    ),
    array(
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => "title_2",
    'text' => "text_2",
    'town' => "town_2",
    'autor' => "autor_2",
    'time' => "time_2"
    ),
);
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<ul >
<?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>
    <li id ="listone" name="listone"><?php echo $row['date'];?></li>
    <li>
    <div >
        <?php echo $row['time'];?> <?php echo $row['title']; ?> <?php echo $row['text'];?> <?php echo $row['town'];?>
        <a href="#popupcomment">comment</a>   
    </div>
    <form name="login-form" action="./comments.php" method="post" >
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>  
            <input type="hidden" name="autorpost" id="autorpost" value="<?php echo $row['autor'];?>"/> 
            <textarea name="text" id="text" ></textarea>    
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment" />          
        </div>  
    </form>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[image: clicking the 1st]
[image: clicking the 2nd]

So as you can see in the screenshots from the chrome inspector. the right values are sent (with nasty form input names, as they don't give context)

Comment: I edit it how you said in my question but the id´s of the input have the value of the last created list item. Thats the curious. I am clueless.

Comment: I can't see why in your snippet. :/ I'll edit with a desktop test data

Comment: If I change the id of listone to `<?php echo $row['id'];?>` All works fine. Only when I set the value of the hidden input element to $id it takes the id of the last created post. :)

Comment: I recommend you a template engine like twig. and a Framework like Symfony2. your code will give you more headaches.

Comment: It had something to do with the popup. I change my code and now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe looking into giving each post a totally unique id UUID had reference that.

You can use `uniqid()` in PHP (but it is not really totally random but okay for your use case). For more secure random UUID you can use [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid).

Just save the unique id as a string in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your help but every post could have a unique id if I change the id of listone to $id that worked well only the insert fails.